# EPiServer SearchDataSource control UseFallbackLanguage property

Tags: c#, .net, search, content-management-system, episerver

How [UseFallbackLanguage](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/P_EPiServer_Web_WebControls_PageDataSource_UseFallbackLanguage.htm) should affect search results? 
I have a following code:

```
<EPiServer:SearchDataSource ID="uiSearchDataSource" runat="server"      
               EnableVisibleInMenu="false" 
               UseFallbackLanguage="true"
               PageLink="<%# PageReference.StartPage %>" 
               LanguageBranches="<%# this.CurrentPage.LanguageBranch %>">
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SearchQuery" QueryStringField="search" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</EPiServer:SearchDataSource>
```

And what I expect is that if I search for "word" then it should be searched in current language, and in all fallback languages for each page. Is thats correct?

Currently I don't see any difference in true or false value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Forget the below part. The SearchDataSource completely overrides the Select method and uses FindPagesWithCriteria. The UseFallbackLanguage property is only used on the PageDataSource and has no effect at all in the inherited SearchDataSource.

<strike>The setting only affects master language fallback. If the page you found is not available in the current language the master language version of the page will be shown.</strike>

It is used in the GetChildren of the PageDataSource which the SearchDataSource inherits from:

<strike>DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(new PageReference(pageID), LanguageSelector.AutoDetect(this.UseFallbackLanguage));</strike>

<strike>Also the way that this is done is buggy, I believe there is still a bug with the AutoDetect method. See the following forum post:</strike>

<strike>http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=35269&epslanguage=en</strike>

Comment: but that code doesn't affect search itself. Only when page data instance is retrieved? That means that search is still going to be performed either in current language branch or in all, but not with regard to fallback ?

Comment: Its so bad idea to have properties, that doing nothing :(